# Что может означать <T> Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Что может означать , это неинициализированный тип?

```
public static void CreateStructuredBuffer<T> (ref ComputeBuffer buffer, T[] data) {
        CreateStructuredBuffer<T> (ref buffer, data.Length);
        buffer.SetData (data);
    }
```

Comment: это часть синтаксиса C#, называется обобщения.

Comment: А к чему оно может применяться, я его часто видел в статичных методах. И что оно может означать?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php

Comment: [Generics](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) - документация. Если владеете английским, лучше читайте на нём.

Comment: Самый просто пример: List<T> - список T типа, например List<int>, List<string>, List<GameObject> и т.д.